# Flutter button new theme copyWith doesn't change color

Tags: flutter, themes

I've got a little piece of code below. It should show "add icon" with blue color. Instead it shows button with black color (as accentColor in MaterialApp).
Am I doing something wrong in "floatingActionButton"?

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    final appName = "Custom Themes";

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: appName,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.red[300],
        accentColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(
        title: appName
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text(title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: new Text(
            "Text with background color",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    floatingActionButton: new Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.blue),
      child: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    )
    );
  }

}
```

I watched a tutorial (it is flutter in iOS) and everything works like a charm there.
Tut is from April 2019. Maybe there is something that changed from that time?

Comment: Why are you not adding color to your icon? Like `Icon(Icons.add, color:Colors.blue)`

Comment: It changes only color of icon not button. Button is still black.

Comment: Ok, you want to change the backgroud color of the FAB, use `backgroundColors: Colors.blue` as FAB attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme:
        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.blue),
      )
```

detail reference https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#complete-example

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    final appName = "Custom Themes";

    return  MaterialApp(
      title: appName,
      theme:  ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.red[300],
        accentColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      home:  MyHomePage(
          title: appName
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return  Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:  Text(title),
        ),
        body:  Center(
          child:  Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child:  Text(
              "Text with background color",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton:  Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme:
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.blue),
          ),
          child:  FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child:  Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I thought about reading documentation.
Noob behaviour.
I changed code to what's in documentation and everything works fine.
Problem is solved.